# How to pass a list from controller to view and display as table

Tags: c#, javascript, json, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting a error, but the error only says the title of my page; when I try to debug and step through the code, it's going into the shared layout.cshtml page, but it steps all the way through, and fails on the footer (where there's only test and an image). I've tried commenting out the footer, and its elements, but that hasn't worked. I can't seem to find anything either using the dev tools in chrome/firefox.

Any hints as to where am I going wrong?

This index.cshtml page originally pointed to a js file,where a layout is defined for the data. I left the layout there, but when it goes to the index, it then redirects it to the listing. Could it be that the js file in the index is causing the error? I've tried commenting it out, but then the page is blank.

The index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}

@section Head {
    @Html.ScriptFile("modules/people.js", false)
}

<div class="header"><span class="name">@ViewBag.Title</span></div>
<table class="data"></table>
```

The people.js file has this:

```
$(function () {
    if ($("#ID").length) {
        init();
} else {
    initializeTable("disclosures/listing", undefined, [
            { "sTitle": "ID" },
            { "sTitle": "Name" },
            { "sTitle": "Job Title" },
            { "sTitle": "Interview Complete?" },
            { "sTitle": "Completed On" },
            { "sTitle": "Last Update" }
        ], [
            { "name": "Completed: ", "column": 3 }
        ]);
      }
});
```

I've got an array of objects (essentially strings) in my Controller:

```
List<PersonStatus> people = new List<PersonStatus>();
```

After adding items to the List, I pass it to my View:

```
return View("Listing", people);
```

and then display the array in the Listing View as a table:

```
@model List<PersonStatus>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}

@section Head {
    @Html.ScriptFile("modules/people.js", false)
}

<div class="header"><span class="name">@ViewBag.Title</span></div>
<div class="overflow"> 

@if (people == null)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <i><font color="#cc0000">Information not available.</font></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
@if (people != null)
{
    <table class="data">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>IDNumber</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Interview Complete?</th>
                <th>Last Updated On</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var p in Model)
            {
               var person = p;

               <tr>
                <td>
                    <th>@people.IDNumber</th>
                    <th>@people.Name</th>
                    <th>@people.JTitle</th>
                    <th>@people.InterviewComplete</th>
                    <th>@people.LastUpdateDate</th>
                </td>
               </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you may need to use foreach loop. like:

```
@if (people != null)
{
    <table class="data">
        <thead>
               <tr>
                <th>IDNumber</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Interview Complete?</th>
                <th>Last Updated On</th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
            foreach (var item in people)
            {
         <tr>
                <td>
                    <th>@item.IDNumber</th>
                    <th>@item.Name</th>
                    <th>@item.JTitle</th>
                    <th>@item.InterviewComplete</th>
                    <th>@item.LastUpdateDate</th>
                </td>
            </tr>
           }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your collection using a foreach loop and create a new table row on each iteration. Check out [Foreach loop for tables in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395085/foreach-loop-for-tables-in-mvc4)

Comment: I've updated the code with what I tried, but I I get a null reference; I think that my issue is more that I'm not getting the data over to the View?

Answer (score 0):

OK,I think you are confused at System.NullReferenceException.
for your View Model you do like that

`@model List<string>`

and in your controller your code is

`List<PersonStatus> people = new List<PersonStatus>();
return View(people);`

the issue is you pass `List<PersonStatus>` to View but you define View Model as `List<String>`
you should do like that

`@model List<PersonStatus>`

please try this code:

```
@model List<PersonStatus>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}

@section Head {
    @Html.ScriptFile("modules/people.js", false)
}

<div class="header"><span class="name">@ViewBag.Title</span></div>
<div class="overflow"> 

@if (Model== null)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <i><font color="#cc0000">Information not available.</font></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
@if (Model!= null)
{
    <table class="data">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>IDNumber</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Interview Complete?</th>
                <th>Last Updated On</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var p in Model)
            {
               <tr>
                <td>
                    <th>@p.IDNumber</th>
                    <th>@p.Name</th>
                    <th>@p.JTitle</th>
                    <th>@p.InterviewComplete</th>
                    <th>@p.LastUpdateDate</th>
                </td>
               </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rick, thanks so much for the suggestions. I've tried that, and I'm seeing the data go over to the model if I use the developer tools in chrome/firefox, but I get an error, and the data won't show on the page. I've updated my post above with your suggestions/my changes, would you be able to suggest anything else for me to try?