# how to use a foreach in a view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, foreach

Trying to pass a list of confirmed orders to the supplier page (checked with breakpoint the list is being past) just having problems using a foreach to display the list in the view.

```
//SupplierController  
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
 BuyABicycle_Entities db1 = new BuyABicycle_Entities();

 IEnumerable<BicycleOrder> All_Orders = (from c in db1.BicycleOrders
                                                    where c.Id >= 1
                                                    select c).ToList();

  SupplierVM model = new SupplierVM { allOrders = All_Orders };
  return View(model);
}


//SupplierVM
public class SupplierVM
{
  public IEnumerable<BicycleOrder> allOrders { get; set; }
}

Views/Supplier/Index
@model BicycleShop.ViewModels.SupplierVM

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Supplier";
        //var orders = (IList<BicycleOrder>) Model.;
        // var orders = (List<BicycleOrder>) Model.Order);
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <table>
        @foreach (var _Order in Model.allOrders)
         {
           <text>
               <tr>
                  <td>@_Order.CustomerName</td>       
               </tr>
            </text>
}

    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

This throws the error with @foreach (var _Order in Model.allOrders)
Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Entity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel, Version=6.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=287b5094865421c0'.

[Foreach loop for tables in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395085/foreach-loop-for-tables-in-mvc4)
do I need to declare a variable for the list at the top and then run through that

any help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view specifies the model as an `IEnumerable<SupplierVM>`. So to iterate over the orders, you would first have to iterate over the suppliers:

```
@foreach (var supplier in Model)
{
    foreach (var order in supplier.allOrders)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, it seems you're not actually passing many `SupplierVM` instances, but just one. Therefore, you should change the view's model to:

```
@model BicycleShop.ViewModels.SupplierVM
```

And, then you can directly iterate over the orders:

```
@foreach (var order in Model.allOrders)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply chris. Yea that was a mistake on my part. the Supplier VM only contains orders, Just to keep it nice and tidy, anyway tried what you suggested and unfortuantely it still isnt working il update the main Q. Something about The type 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Entity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. if you have any more ideas that would be great

Comment: That's entirely unrelated. That is an actual error somewhere in your code. Namely, somewhere you're reference a class, `Entity` from an `IdeaBlade.EntityModel` namespace and that namespace does not exist in your references or the namespace does not contain a class named `Entity`.

Comment: ahh yes I was using the table from the entity framework when I should have beeing populating the class in the model folder. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

maybe razor is getting confused between HTML and code:

try this:

```
    @foreach (var _Order in Model)
    {
        <text>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.allOrders)</td>
            <td>@_Order.allOrders</td>
            @<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CustomerName, new { @readonly = true }) </td>
            @foreach(var item in _Order)
             {
                 item.ItemProp <br />
             }
        </tr>
        </text>
    }
```

inside the `{}` razor is expecting it all the be code, if you want to put HTML in there - multi-line use `<text></text>`  for one line use `@:`

Comment: Im sorry this isnt working either 4 erros with it.im not sure if i needed the second foreach was just trying to figure it out. the model contains a list of BicycleOrders - allOrders. i want to loop through and output each order 'CustomerName, CustomerAddress, Model' etc...all found in each BicycleOrder